# Trying to update service access policies in CloudSearch with the java sdk

Tags: java, amazon-cloudsearch

I'm trying to update access policies for an Amazon CloudSearch domain in java code, and it appears to be possible but the API for it seems to be lacking. My code so far is:

```
cloudSearchClient.updateServiceAccessPolicies(
            new UpdateServiceAccessPoliciesRequest()
                    .withDomainName("test-eme1")
                    .withAccessPolicies("???"));
```

The UpdateServiceAccessPoliciesRequest only takes in two parameters: The CloudSearch domain (a String) and the Access Policies (another String).

The online documentation and javadoc for 'withAccessPolicy' both have this to say:
*"The access rules you want to configure. These rules replace existing rules."*

The mere fact that you're supposed to define multiple access rules here with a single String means that the UpdateServiceAccessPoliciesRequest class is a poly designed container for an http request, and I can live with that, but does anyone know what an "Access Policies" update String looks like in this context?

I'm using the AWS Java SDK version 1.7.9, which I'm almost positive uses the CloudSearch REST API version 2013-01-01.

Answer (score 0):

I dug in further, and found out that the UpdateServiceAccessPoliciesRequest get's serialized into x-www-form-urlencoded, and that the AccessPolicies parameter is expecting a big old JSON String:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS":["*"]
      },
      "Action":"cloudsearch:*",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:cloudsearch:us-east-1:000123456789:domain/test-eme1",
      "Condition":{
        "IpAddress":{
          "aws:SourceIp":["0.0.0.0/0"]
         }
       }
     }
  ]
}
```

Where 'Statement' is a list of rule changes.

Hopefully this saves someone else a similar headache :)